# How to handle frontawesome url-load issue in webpack4?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I am working on a react project with `webpack4`. I added a import code in my js file:

```
@import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';
```

After than I got below error on compiling.

```
        ERROR in ./css/waffle/waffle.scss (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./css/waffle/waffle.scss)
        Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0' in 'TheFrontEnd/css/waffle'
```

I did some search and it seems a configuration for resolving the path has an issue but I have configured `webpack` to use load the `woff2` file. Below is the loader configuration in `webpack`:

```
module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js?$/,
                    exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                    loader: 'file-loader'
                },
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    use: [
                        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        'css-loader',
                        'resolve-url-loader',
                        'postcss-loader',
                        'sass-loader'
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader!resolve-url-loader']
                },
                {
                    test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                    loader: 'file-loader?limit=10000'
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(ttf|eot)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                    loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'
                },
                {
                    test: /\.html?$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'html-loader',
                            options: {
                                attrs: false
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
                    loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000'
                } // load small <10kb images into base 64 into css
            ]
        },
```

This path `../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0` is reference from `node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css`. How can I make it work? Can anyone see anything wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a loader issue, it's a resolver issue. I ran into this a couple of time, but never had the patient to look into it carefully. I suspect it's webpack not having a good enough resolver setup for `.scss` use case.

Anyway, here's my quick fix:

1. Find out what's the exact absolute path of that font file
2. Add alias to it

```
webpackConfig = {
  reaolve: {
    alias: {
      'fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2': '/abs/to/to/that/woff2'
    ...
}
```